# Accessing unique key in Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

For help with userIds in photo in Firebase RealTime Database
mUser.uid!!
There is simple code.

```
lateinit var mUser: as FirebaseUser..
```

I am trying to access the id of the posts in users.

```
mRef.child("users").child(mUser.uid!!).child("posts").child(?????)
```

'?' What should be written where it says?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this? (Assuming you want to access the node "message" of the unknown child.

```
mRef.child("users").child(mUser.uid).child("posts").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                //childSnapshot is the unknow ID so if the posts have a node called "message" then following will retrieve it
                // childSnapshot is your unique key. You can acces its children by calling childSnapshot.child(name_of_your_child_here)
                String postMessage = childSnapshot.child("message");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }         
    });
```

"childSnapshot" is your unique key.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer if it solves your problem (it does!)